# SQL Insert Only First Letter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

MY SQL PROCEDURE IS

```
create proc sp_tblAppRegistration
(
@Action varchar(100) = null,
@ID int  = null,
@RegCode varchar (100) = null,
@FirstName varchar(50) = null,
@MiddleName varchar (50)= null,
@LastName varchar (50)= null,
@Email varchar (100)= null,
@EmailVerified bit = null,
@MobileNo varchar (20) = null,
@DateOFBirth varchar (20)= null,
@StateID int  = null,
@CityID int  = null,
@EmailVerificationCode varchar (50)= null

)
WITH RECOMPILE
AS BEGIN

IF @Action = 'Register'
    BEGIN

         declare @newRegCode varchar(max) = 'TM-'+ cast((select count(*)+1 from tblRegistration) as varchar(10));  
         declare @VerificationCode varchar(max) = (select left(NEWID(),8));
         --//======================================

            insert into tblAppRegistration(RegCode,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName
            ,Email,EmailVerified,MobileNo,DateOFBirth,StateID,CityID,
            ,EmailVerificationCode)
            values
            (@newRegCode,@FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName,@Email,'false',@MobileNo,@DateOFBirth,@StateID
            ,@CityID,@VerificationCode)

            select EmailVerificationCode, RegCode from  tblRegistration order by CreationDate desc
    END


 END
```

when query inserts they give me return value as expected, but my entry should be entered in the table only First Letter of value that I am inserted.

OUTPUT

```
    ID| RegCode | FirstName | MiddleName    | LastName  | Email | EmailVerified | MobileNo  | DateOFBirth   | StateID   | CityID | EmailVerificationCode |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1 | TM-1    |  t        |   s           |   m       | t     |   0      |    9       |   1           | 1         |1       |6D8F989A               |
```

whats the problem in that is any thing wrong please help me .

Comment: Show your entire procedure.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs when you leave out the length.  In many situations, the default for a character string with no length is one.

So, if the stored procedure is defined as:

```
create procedure x (
    @FirstName varchar,
    . . .
)
begin
. . .
end;
```

Then the length is "1" by default.  You can easily fix this by adding a length:

```
create procedure x (
    @FirstName varchar(255),
    . . .
)
begin
. . .
end;
```

This is also true if you use `declare`:

```
declare @FirstName varchar;
```

is equivalent to:

```
declare @FirstName varchar(1);
```

Moral?  In SQL Server, always include the length when using `varchar()` and related types.

Comment: I don't know what problem but I delete that procedure and recreate it works

Comment: How fast can the speed of the store processor?

Answer (score 2):

To get the first character all you have to do is below : -

```
LEFT(colName, 1)

Insert into table(Fields,.....) values(Left(@newRegCode , 1), ....)
```